# plotting conditional distribution in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm new to python and trying to plot a gaussian distribution having the function defined as

[image]

I plotted normal distribution P(x,y) and it's giving correct output. code and output are below.

Code : 
[image]

Output : 
[image]

Now I need to plot a conditional distribution [image]  and the output should like [image]. to do this I need to define a boundary condition for the equation. I tried to define a boundary condition but it's not working. the code which I tried is [image]  but it's giving wrong output
[image]  please help me how to plot the same.

Thanks,

Comment: It would be better to put the python codes as a text code instead of picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the boundary condition on the wrong parameter, try to do it after creating the grid points.

```
R = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(R, R)
```

then validate X and Y based on the condition

```
valid_xy = np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2) >= 1

X = X[valid_xy]
Y = Y[valid_xy]
```

Then  continue with the rest of the code.

**Update**

If you want just to reset values around the peak to zero, you can use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(R, R)

Z = np.sum(np.exp(-0.5*(X**2+Y**2)))
P = (1/Z)*np.exp(-0.5*(X**2+Y**2))

# reset the peak
invalid_xy = (X**2+Y**2)<1
P[invalid_xy] = 0

# plot the result 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X, Y, P, s=0.5, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: but with this I'm facing one issue. the inner circle is not coming.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I have one more doubt can you answer the same ?? I'm struggling to understand "Marginalise the conditional distribution(above solved) over y and plot Q(x)" and please let me know where I can learn more about probability plotting via python.

Comment: projection = '3d' does not work, until from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `np.meshgrid` anymore because it will output a matrix where the coordinates of X and Y form a grid (hence its name) and not a custom shape (a grid minus a disc like you want):

However you can create your custom grid the following way:

```
R = np.arange(-,4,0.1)
xy_coord = np.array(((x,y) for x in R for y in R if (x*x + y*y) > 1))
X,Y = xy_coord.transpose()
X
# array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. , ...,  3.9,  3.9,  3.9])
Y
# array([ 1.1,  1.2,  1.3, ...,  3.7,  3.8,  3.9])
```